# Rasterio equivalent for GDAL's GetProjection() and GetGeoTransform()?

Tags: python, geospatial, gdal, rasterio

I have a GeoTIFF that I've done a lot of processing with in OpenCV. After processing, its lost its spatial information so I need to insert it back in. In GDAL, I would just extract that from the original image before processing and then just shove it back in with the post-processed image like so:

```
#open original geotiff
original_img = gdal.Open('/path-to-file/original_img.tif', 1)
crs = original_img.GetProjection()
gt = original_img.GetGeoTransform()
del original_ds

#open cv processes here....write post-processed file

# open processed raster and set the projection and geotransform
img = gdal.Open('/path-to-file/processed_img.tif', 1)
img.SetProjection(crs)
img.SetGeoTransform(gt)
```

Is there a way I can do this in Rasterio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [RasterIO documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#dataset-georeferencing), you can simply access `crs` and `transform` attributes on an open dataset to get the projection and geotransform respectively. You can then pass them back to output image file [on opening](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#opening-a-dataset-in-writing-mode).

Example:

```py
# Open original Geotiff
original_img = rasterio.open("path/to/input.tif")
# Extract spatial metadata
input_crs = original_img.crs
input_gt  = original.transform

# Do your processing. For this example, just read first band of input dataset
processed_img = original_img.read(1)

# Prepare output geotiff file. We give crs and gt read from input as spatial metadata
with rasterio.open(
  'path/to/output.tif',
  'w',
  driver = 'GTiff',
  count = 1,
  height = processed_img.shape[0],
  width  = processed_img.shape[1],
  dtype  = processed_img.dtype,
  crs    = input_crs,
  transform = input_gt  
) as output:
  output.write(processed_img, 1)
```

*Notes on above example* :

- assume that image dimensions are preserved when processing it. If not, you'll have to derive the spatial transform accordingly.
- Assume single-band dataset

Comment: Thanks. Where is processed_img to be defined? I added a line above but it tells me that there is no .dtype attribute. Hm.

Comment: It's undefined in my example. It's a placeholder for the resulting image from your processing (for testing, it could be defined as  the first band of input dataset: `original_img.read(1)`).

Comment: Could you show how it would be written in generic terms? It's saying there's no dtype associated to my processed image when I read it back in as `processed_img = rasterio.open('/Users/me/processed_img.tif')` However, it's shown as an 8 bit unsigned integer when I open it in QGIS.

Comment: When opening a file with rasterio, you acquire a `dataset`, that contains a `dtypes` attribute, which is a tuple giving the data type of each band of the read file. You need to read a band (`dataset.read(band))`) to obtain an image with a `dtype` attribute. I've updated my example to initialize `processed_img` to be the first band of input file.

Comment: Thanks! I also ended up bypassing the issue by uploading the processed image with cv2.imread() instead. Appreciate the amendment, though.